# Why wasn't Hermione punished for the polyjuice potion

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

It is said that making the polyjuice potion Harry, Ron and Hermione were breaking at least 50 rules of the school. Now, Hermione accidentally drinks a potion with an addition of cat's hair, which sends her to the hospital wing for weeks.
How did she justify accidentally turning into half a cat? If she admitted or was found guilty of brewing the polyjuice potion, why weren't all three punished in some way?
I know the book says that Madam Pomfrey "never asks too many questions" but for sure the voice of the accident would have spread, especially since the only place they could have gotten the ingredients is stealing them from Snape, and judging by the fourth book, he discovers this kind of stuff.

It looks like the cat accident with the polyjuice potion isn't that relevant to the story and it introduces an unnecessary plot hole. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: What happens in the Infirmary stays in the infirmary

Comment: You've answered your own question. Madame Pomfrey is discreet.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but everyone else is not. The question linked doesn't mention the hospital wing, but the answer does. The explanation is still unsatisfactory but I guess there isn't a better one (I think ingredients missing from Snape's store and a botched transfiguration is proof enough, or at least enough to start some kind of investigation!). I still wonder why the writer decided to include this accident even if it was not very relevant and introduced this plot hole.

Comment: Not every unresolved plot point is a 'plot hole'

Comment: Isn't staying as a cat for weeks a punishment?

Comment: Isn't the book to make polyjuice in the library? Didn't Hermione say it's beyond their grade? I doubt the kids get punished for practicing legal magic in school.

Comment: I would take a guess, and it is only that, that the policy is intentional -- If students had to worry about repercussions from seeking help in the infirmity it would tend to make them less likely to do so.. and put them at greater risk.  Much the way some companies won't fire you if you seek treatment for alcoholism, drugs, etc., BEFORE they call you on it, I suspect Madame Pomfrey would rather treat you, lecture you in private about it, and leave it at that, and the administration, recognizing the effectiveness of this tactic, goes along with her.

Comment: It's just a spell gone wrong to the nurse.